# Aligning buttons in center of background

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS etc.

I'm trying to align 2 buttons next to each other, in center of the background image, so it stays in position even when the window is being resized.

Image for illustration: [image]

Code:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('/image/bgcopy.png'), url(/image/bg2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
  background-size: contain, cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.button2 {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button button1"><a href="/nl">Lang1</a></button>
  <button class="button button2"><a href="/fr">Lang2</a></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, maybe you could try:

```
.container{    
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Or have you seen anything about [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)? Since you want it to be responsive, I think it might be the best altenative.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you creating two classes with same properties? first you can remove properties from classes: button1 and button2 and then add these properties to button class like this:

```
.button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    /* properties from class button1 or button2 */
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And in button1 and button2 class add codes below to center these:

```
.button1 {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    top: 50%;
}

.button2 {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    left: 60%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Don't change HTML code, classes are same.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS code and change the top and left values as you need;

```
.btncenter{
 top:50%;
 left:40%;
 position: absolute;
 width:550px;
}
```

Edit HTML Code look like this;

```
<div class="btncenter">
    <button class="button button1"><a href="/nl">Lang1</a></button>
    <button class="button button2"><a href="/fr">Lang2</a></button>
  </div>
```

---

Below Final code sample you can view;

```css
body {
  background-image: url('/image/bgcopy.png'), url(/image/bg2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
  background-size: contain, cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.button2 {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.btncenter{
 top:50%;
 left:40%;
position: absolute;
width:550px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="btncenter">
    <button class="button button1"><a href="/nl">Lang1</a></button>
    <button class="button button2"><a href="/fr">Lang2</a></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use @media queries per-width of the screen.
With `position : absolute;` and just play the `top` or `left` value as you need :D

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to do it. The code below will keep the buttons separated from each other until there is no space left. This should give you a start.

You can also use `position: fixed` if you need a more fixed solution. But I will recommend playing with `flex` property. It should solve most of the use-cases.

```css
.btn-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

button {
  background: pink;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-container"> <button class="first">Button 1</button><button class="second">Button 1</button></div>
```